# Which TypeScript/JavaScript unit test framework that has an API most similar to JUnit?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking to port a significant number of tests written in JUnit to test TypeScript code on Node.js.   I know that annotations are an experimental feature in TypeScript/JavaScript, but ideally, it would use the same `@Before`, `@Test`, and `@After` source annotations that JUnit does.

Output in the same [JUnit XML format](http://help.catchsoftware.com/display/ET/JUnit+Format) would be plus as well.

Answer (score 2):

I know that I might be kind of late with my answer, but you might want to checkout [TestyTs](https://github.com/Testy/TestyTs)

It supports annotations similar to JUnit:

```
@TestSuite()
export class MyTestSuite {

    @BeforeEach()
    beforeEach() {
        // Do something
    }

    @Test()
    onePlusOne() {
        const result = 1 + 1;
        expect.toBeEqual(result, 2);
    }

    @AfterEach()
    afterEach() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Try it on [REPL](https://repl.it/@Aboisier/TestyTs-Playground#src/tests.spec.ts)

Answer (score 1):

> but ideally, it would use the same @Before, @Test, and @After source annotations that JUnit does.

None of the popular js frameworks out there do that right now. Fwiw Mocha is the king of the test frameworks at the moment e.g. npm downloads http://www.npmtrends.com/mocha-vs-jasmine-vs-qunit-vs-jest-vs-ava

## More

- It is the test framework that is used by the TypeScript team : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d1ac8dde0b2a9bc4929cc45a918e29dda651dafe/package.json#L69
- Hence it is the framework that I support in alm as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/testing.html